# Persisting jQuery autocomplete textbox after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am retrieving a list of data asychronously with jQuery ajax and calling autocomplete on a textbox to bind the data on the jQuery page ready event. The autocomplete textbox works as expected. What doesn't work is when the user hits the submit button on the form and there is a validation error. The page does not refill the textbox with the last known value. I know HTTP is a stateless protocol. I'm torn between trying to manually insert the value back into the textbox with razor or trying to mess with the autocomplete settings to somehow repopulate the selected value. What should I do?

```
success: function (data) {

                //reappend data - get drop down list
                log("got data", data);

                var arr = [];

                $.each(data.vendors, function (i, val) {

                    arr.push({ label: val.Name, value: val.Name, item: val.Value });

                });

                var ele = $page.find("#vendorAuto");

                ele.autocomplete({ source: arr, html: true, select: function (event, ui) {

                    $page.find("#VendorID").val(ui.item.item);

                }});
```

Comment: Stupid question but how does your validation look. Is it Unobtrusive ajax validation? I ask because it sounds like you are doing a full page refresh and the values in that case would not persist.

Comment: You are right in saying that it is a full page refresh and that the values are not persisting. Validation is written in Razor and would be considered server side. On the controller action we have if (Model.IsValid) { do(); } return View(model);

Answer (score 0):

how about using session, cookies or cache to store the selected items value, then test the value on page load and if there is a value there, use that to set the dropdown.